# Bug in React Code while making a login/signup using firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication

I am making a react app and I encountered a weird bug when I tried to make login/signup of my app. In my App whenever a user is logged in I want to show them a particular piece of code and if the user is not logged in then I want to show them the login/signup page. Now the problem is that my code works fine if I type some simple piece of code after logged in state but doesn't work fine with Grids of material-ui.

**Here is My App.js which works as expected.** (Hello world gets printed in browser after I login) but the nothing gets printed on console.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import Home from "./components/pages/Home"
import About from './components/pages/About';
import Contact from './components/pages/Contact';
import Navbar from './components/layout/Navbar';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch}from 'react-router-dom';
import Error from './components/pages/Error';
import AddBooking from './components/Bookings/AddBooking';
import EditBooking from './components/Bookings/EditBooking';
import ViewBooking from './components/Bookings/ViewBooking';
import Bookings from './components/pages/Bookings';
import Booking2 from './components/pages/Booking2';
import Login from './components/pages/login';
import fire from './fire';
import SidePanel from './components/layout/SidePanel';
import {Grid} from "@material-ui/core";

function App() {
    

    const[user, setUser]= useState('');
    const[email, setEmail]= useState('');
    const[password, setPassword]= useState('');
    const[emailError, setEmailError]= useState('');
    const[passwordError, setPasswordError]= useState('');
    const[hasAccount, setHasAccount]= useState(false);

    const clearInputs=()=>{
        setEmail('');
        setPassword('');
    }

    const clearErrors=()=>{
        setEmailError('');
        setPasswordError('');
    }

    const handleLogin=()=>{
        clearErrors();
        fire
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
        .catch((err)=>{                             
            switch(err.code){
                case "auth/invalid-email":
                case "auth/user-disabled":
                case "auth/user-not-found":
                    setEmailError(err.message);
                    break;
                case "auth/wrong-password":
                    setPasswordError(err.message);
                    break;
            }
        });
    };

    const handleSignup=()=>{
        clearErrors();
        fire
        .auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
        .catch((err)=>{                             
            switch(err.code){
                case "auth/email-already-in-use":
                case "auth/invalid-email":
                    setEmailError(err.message);
                    break;
                case "auth/weak-password":
                    setPasswordError(err.message);
                    break;
            }
        });
    };

    const handleLogout=()=>{
        fire.auth().signOut();
    };

    const authListener=()=>{
        fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user=>{
            if(user){
                clearInputs();
                setUser(user);
            }else{
                setUser("");
            }
        });
    };

    useEffect(()=>{
        authListener();
    }, []);

  
    return (

    <Router>
        {user?(
            <div>
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
            {console.log("this statement doesn't print on console")};
            </div>
        ):(
            <Login 
                email={email} 
                setEmail={setEmail}
                password={password}
                setPassword={setPassword}
                handleLogin={handleLogin}
                handleSignup={handleSignup}
                hasAccount={hasAccount}
                setHasAccount={setHasAccount}
                emailError={emailError}
                passwordError={passwordError}
                clearInputs={clearInputs}
                clearErrors={clearErrors}
            />
        )}
    </Router>
    );
}

export default App;
```

**Here is App.js which doesn't works as expected.**. The Below code is same as above (Just replaced the hello world statement with other piece of code). The bug is that I still remain on the login page after I press the login button.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import Home from "./components/pages/Home"
import About from './components/pages/About';
import Contact from './components/pages/Contact';
import Navbar from './components/layout/Navbar';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch}from 'react-router-dom';
import Error from './components/pages/Error';
import AddBooking from './components/Bookings/AddBooking';
import EditBooking from './components/Bookings/EditBooking';
import ViewBooking from './components/Bookings/ViewBooking';
import Bookings from './components/pages/Bookings';
import Booking2 from './components/pages/Booking2';
import Login from './components/pages/login';
import fire from './fire';
import SidePanel from './components/layout/SidePanel';
import {Grid} from "@material-ui/core";

function App() {
    

    const[user, setUser]= useState('');
    const[email, setEmail]= useState('');
    const[password, setPassword]= useState('');
    const[emailError, setEmailError]= useState('');
    const[passwordError, setPasswordError]= useState('');
    const[hasAccount, setHasAccount]= useState(false);

    const clearInputs=()=>{
        setEmail('');
        setPassword('');
    }

    const clearErrors=()=>{
        setEmailError('');
        setPasswordError('');
    }

    const handleLogin=()=>{
        clearErrors();
        fire
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
        .catch((err)=>{                             
            switch(err.code){
                case "auth/invalid-email":
                case "auth/user-disabled":
                case "auth/user-not-found":
                    setEmailError(err.message);
                    break;
                case "auth/wrong-password":
                    setPasswordError(err.message);
                    break;
            }
        });
    };

    const handleSignup=()=>{
        clearErrors();
        fire
        .auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
        .catch((err)=>{                             
            switch(err.code){
                case "auth/email-already-in-use":
                case "auth/invalid-email":
                    setEmailError(err.message);
                    break;
                case "auth/weak-password":
                    setPasswordError(err.message);
                    break;
            }
        });
    };

    const handleLogout=()=>{
        fire.auth().signOut();
    };

    const authListener=()=>{
        fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user=>{
            if(user){
                clearInputs();
                setUser(user);
            }else{
                setUser("");
            }
        });
    };

    useEffect(()=>{
        authListener();
    }, []);

  
    return (

    <Router>
        {user?(
            <div>
            <Grid container direction="column">
                <Grid item>
                    <Navbar />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item container>
                    <Grid item xs={false} sm={2}>
                        <SidePanel handleLogout={handleLogout()}/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={10}>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                            <Route exact path="/Bookings" component={Bookings}/>
                            <Route exact path="/Booking2" component={Booking2}/>
                            <Route exact path="/about" component={About}/>
                            <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
                            <Route exact path="/Bookings/add" component={AddBooking}/>
                            <Route exact path="/Bookings/edit/:id" component={EditBooking}/>
                            <Route exact path="/Bookings/view/:id" component={ViewBooking}/>
                            <Route component={Error}/>
                        </Switch>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
            </div>
        ):(
            <Login 
                email={email} 
                setEmail={setEmail}
                password={password}
                setPassword={setPassword}
                handleLogin={handleLogin}
                handleSignup={handleSignup}
                hasAccount={hasAccount}
                setHasAccount={setHasAccount}
                emailError={emailError}
                passwordError={passwordError}
                clearInputs={clearInputs}
                clearErrors={clearErrors}
            />
        )}
    </Router>
    );
}

export default App;
```

I am unable to find out what is wrong. There is something silly which I am missing but unable to figure out.

**EDIT-**
There is something wrong with handleLogout Statement, Everything works fine without it.

**SidePanel.js** (The handleLogout is called here)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import * as FaIcons from 'react-icons/fa';
import * as AiIcons from 'react-icons/ai';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { SidebarData } from './SidebarData';
import { IconContext } from 'react-icons';
import '../../static/SidePanel.css';
import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core';

const SidePanel=({handleLogout})=> {
    return (
        <>
        <Grid container>
            <div className='side-panel-menu'>
                <ul className='side-panel-items'>
                    {SidebarData.map((item, index) => {
                    return (
                        <li key={index} className={item.cName}>
                        <Link to={item.path}>
                            {item.icon}
                            <span>{item.title}</span>
                        </Link>
                        </li>
                    );
                    })}
                    <li>
                    <button className="Sidebar-logout-button" onClick={handleLogout}>Logout</button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </Grid>
        </>
    );
}

export default SidePanel;
```

Comment: any clue in the console output? have you tried adding some console.log's to see wht your code is doing? or `debuggger` to debug your code?

Comment: I edited my hello world example a little bit. (Have a look again). Code working fine in browser but nothing prints on console.

Comment: There is something wrong with handleLogout Statement, Everything works fine without it.

Comment: I think it gets called of its own when I try to login. But how and why?